# 2d random walk average hitting time for 4 corners

Tags: stochastic-processes

I have found out that 1 and 2 dimensional random walks are recurrent. But considering the scenario of an infinite 2d space where the "targets" lie on the point (±2,±2). Is it possible to reach one of these 4 points within a limited time? If yes, what is the average time taken?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Those are two different questions. It's certainly possible to reach one of those points within a limited time – that doesn't mean that the expected time exists / is finite.

Comment: Would you care to explain?